# Terminating a Cloud SQL Import Process

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I ran an import process in a Cloud SQL instance, but as it turns out, there are several checks that needs to be done before the import process can begin. Now, I need to terminate the process, but I find no cancel/stop button anywhere. The import reads from a 82 GB, so it'd be too long to wait for it to be done. Is there any way I can terminate the process immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [public documentation for Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export#tips_for_long-running_import_and_export_processes)

> You cannot stop a long-running operation

You have to wait until the operation finish

Comment: Yeah, seems like there's no other way short of asking support to do it.

Answer (score 0):

One dirty trick I found is to manually delete database that is getting actually imported. That will result in RDBMS type of import error and effectively terminate the import.